# Can we add a feature where you gain reputation points for earning badges?

Tags: feature-request

Today I realised that badges don't give you reputation points. I thought that it would be a great idea to give +5 or +10 points for each badge earned. Could we make this a feature please?

Comment: This should be posted on https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You have to make this request at StackExchange meta, because this feature needs to be implemented in all the sites. But before you do, one very important tip, make sure this request has not already been proposed, you need to search in their archives. If you don't, and the FR has already been proposed and rejected, you risk being buried under an avalanche of downvotes, for lack of research and prep. I'm speaking from experience :)

Comment: P.S I don't think this [**feature request**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=requests) (see SE meta link for a list of top FRs) is a good idea at all. The upvotes (and downvotes) are about questions and answers, the badges are just tokens, merely visible reminders, nothing more or less.

Comment: It's always worth asking this sort of question in a site meta first, because it gives an idea of support before risking your M.SE reputation with a post there. Meta.SE is (perhaps paradoxically) a main site with **real** rep points to win or lose.

Comment: I agree with @AndrewLeach. It's a good place for new users to learn how Stack Exchange works without getting heavily downvoted as this question, [Rep “prize money” when badges are awarded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196790/rep-prize-money-when-badges-are-awarded).

Comment: Scratch everything I said, I was totally wrong. Your question is on topic for ELU.

Answer (score 6):

I can understand that, early in membership of the community when reputation is hard-earned and badges come somewhat more easily, a badge-related way of earning points looks attractive.

However, it actually defeats the purpose of reputation points.

Badges are a measure of involvement: how much you have done. Your reputation is a measure of **how the community values your posts** on the main site. It's a fundamental measure. Stack Exchange sites exist to provide good answers to good questions, and gaining reputation from good answers or good questions is a mark of your participation in that goal.

That said, there are some things that do gain you reputation: you gain +2 points for every suggested edit (up to a limit), because you are improving things and helping the site to host good questions and good answers. You get +2 points when you accept an answer to a question you've asked, because again by accepting an answer you're helping to curate the site content.

However you gain far more reputation by actually providing that content. For every upvote on a good question, you gain +5 points. For every upvote on a good answer, you get +10. If your answer is accepted by the question asker, you get another +15. It is providing this good content which gains reputation, because the community values your input to the body of knowledge it holds.

Badges and points are actually very different. They are kept apart for good reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Andrew's great answer, I'd like to highlight the fact that badges don't work in the same way as reputation does. For example, you need to give up your own 50 to 500 reputation points to earn the [*Altruist* and *Investor*](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges) badges which are awarded to users for

> First bounty you manually award on another person's question
>
> First bounty you offer on another person's question

It doesn't work well for Stack Exchange to award reputation when you try to give up some of your reputation. Out of 138,000 users on ELU, only 77 and 94 users have those badges respectively.

Many badges in Question, Answer and Tag badges come along with reputation. Therefore, if you want to get more badges, you have to participate more in asking and answering questions in a more useful and clear way.

You can't get Moderation badges if you don't participate in moderation activities, such as flagging, voting, editing, etc. It's not always true the higher reputation you have, the more badges you have, especially on Meta. You don't gain any reputation from activities on Meta, but only badges. We can know how active a user is by looking at the number of badges on Meta.

In a related question on Meta Stack Exchange, [Reputation for Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152/reputation-for-badges), @JonSkeet answers:

> I don't think so. Badges tend to come via the same sort of actions which gain you reputation anyway... I don't think it makes sense to make the reputation system even more complicated in this way.

In another related post on Meta SE,  [Rep "prize money" when badges are awarded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196790/rep-prize-money-when-badges-are-awarded) (which was closed as duplicate of the above question), @AdamLear answers:

> When someone joins a site, their goal shouldn't be editing, flagging, commenting, etc. It should be asking and answering questions, at least to start with.

You should note that if you propose this on Meta SE, it will be closed as duplicate of the first question unless you show more convincing arguments than other questions. Also, downvotes on Meta SE are cast more aggressively than English Language & Usage Meta.